# simple regex seemingly not working c++

Tags: c++, regex

Trying to find a regex to indicate whether the right side of an equation has an 'M' or not. This is what I have:

```
^[^=\\s@0-9;(D|A)]+(?==)
```

Here's how I translate this:

```
^ - assert start of line

[everything in brackets] - match one or more characters NOT in these brackets

(?==) - positive lookahead... but now that I'm actually writing this out I think this might be the error.
```

I've been developing my regex's on www.regex101.com on the php default (I know, dumb, but I can't find an online C++ version). It's just hard to predict the behavior doing it this way, and when I have something that seems like it would work, it only partially works.

So,

```
M=D-M  // should indicate M on RHS
D=D+A  // should not indicate M on RHS
D=A    // should not indicate M on RHS
```

It's possible my code has a subtle bug not related to the Regex, but I'm pretty sure that's not the case. It works for dozens of cases with only 2-3 errors. Let's assume its related to regex.

P.S. I'm trying to parse some simple .asm files...

HELP!

Comment: An equation being defined by an 'M' followed by 0 or more alpha-numeric characters and underscores, optional spaces, followed by an equals sign? For instance, `Mikey =` should match but not `Mikey`, `Aikey =`, etc?

Comment: @JefréN check edits in a minute

Comment: Regular expressions are gross overkill for such a simple text search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[^=]+=([^=]*[M][^=]*)$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Isn't it supposed to match equations that start with a capital m?

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin Your comment makes no sense.  Do you want to _capture_ what comes after the equals sign?

Comment: The LHS in my regex is generic and has no restrictions.  It doesn't change the logic for finding an `M` in the RHS.  I added a capture group around the RHS if this is what you have in mind.

Comment: How about something like, " find the first '=', then tell me if there exists at least one 'M' after the '='.

Comment: Is this what you have in mind: `^[^=]+=([^=]*[M]).*$` ? ... this will check for an `M` after the _first_ equals sign, any anything can follow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126779/discussion-between-dylan-larkin-and-tim-biegeleisen).